# How to use Vue Cal without Babel, Webpack, or anything else but a code editor and a CDN

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue JS and I don't know how to use this component: https://antoniandre.github.io/vue-cal/.

I do not have Babel, webpack, or nothing else but a code editor.

How can I use this in my Vue app?

In the documentation says that if I want to add the component trough a  tag just add the tags and then add:

```
// In your VueJS component.
export default {
  components: { 'vue-cal': vuecal },
  ...
}
```

But I tried and console shows: `Unexpected token default`

Comment: `A Vue JS full calendar, no dependency, no BS` - Forgot about Vue being a pretty big dependency there then....

Comment: We need your own code to have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me, code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMpVMv